# Puedo ver todos los registros (GET) pero no puedo seleccionar uno (GET/:id)...alguna idea que me pueda ayudar? Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, api

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  #before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users
    # commented out because a jbuilder template has been added
  end

  # GET /users/1
  def show
    render json: @user
    # commented out because a jbuilder template has been added
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, louserion: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render json: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

La acción `show` utiliza la variable `@user`, la cual es creada en el *callback* `before_action`; pero tienes comentada esa línea, por lo que `@user` está en blanco al momento de ser utilizada en `show`.

Simplemente habilita la línea con el *callback*:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  ...
end
```

`index` funciona correctamente pues no necesita de esa variable, utiliza `@users`, la cual estás creando dentro de la misma acción.